# Android 3d cube animation

Tags: android, animation, transition

I want to make a screen (or part of the screen) switch to another part in a 3D cube-like transition. I'm talking about 2 normal Android UI parts, not raw graphics rendered on a canvas.

How would you approach this?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you can play around with scaling/brightness. Again, this is just me speculating.

Comment: I am using view_flipper to show the child views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should take a look at samples that come with [default android installation](http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html) (>>>Views >>> Animation >>> 3D transition) and searching for some others on [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=android%20Views/Animation/3D%20transition&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enTH438TH438&oq=android%20Views/Animation/3D%20transition&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3j64.16181&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)